# Is it possible in Jmeter to get overall response time with including rendering of page in browser

Tags: api, browser, jmeter, performance-testing, client-side

I have a requirement from client that The overall response time (end to end time including rendering of page in browser) should be 3 secs for all the requests.Its an API with frontend.

As i know jmeter handles server side response time, even if i add embedded resource it just downloads java script ,images etc but doesn't act as a browser. Is there any way where i can get The overall response time (end to end time including rendering of page in browser) .

Could some please help me out with this.Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JMeter Plugin WebDriver Sampler with associated -Driver Config Elements to achieve overall response time.

Following Links could be useful

1. [Web Driver](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) Tutorial
2. Web Driver [Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=WebDriverSampler)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, as per [JMeter project main](https://jmeter.apache.org/) page:

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So the only way of getting client-side metrics like rendering time you need to use a real browser, for example kick off one using [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler). Metrics can be obtained from [Navigation Timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) API via [WebDriver.executeScript() function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: I have some confusion here. If we select retrieve embedded resource in jmeter ,doesn't it give almost same response time as the browser? . If there are API requests does adding retreive embedded resource make sense?